# How can I add a border to my react-konva shape?

Tags: reactjs, konvajs, react-konva

I have a React project with TypeScript. I'm using the react-konva package to draw some shapes.
How can I add to my shape a border like at HTML (`border: 1px solid black`)?

**My code:**

```
       <Rect
          x={103}
          y={103}
          width={144}
          height={44}
          // here i need a border
          fill="#E2E6EA"
          draggable
          onDragStart={this.handleDragStart}
          onDragEnd={this.handleDragEnd}
        />
```

Comment: You can use `drawBorder` property in react-konva. [Source](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Rect.html) or can use propeties `strokeWidth: 10, stroke: 'lime'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the border using `strokeWidth` & `stroke` attributes.

```
<Rect
    x={103}
    y={103}
    width={144}
    height={44}
    // here i need a border
    fill="#E2E6EA"
    draggable
    onDragStart={this.handleDragStart}
    onDragEnd={this.handleDragEnd}
    strokeWidth={1} // border width
    stroke="red" // border color
/>
```